# add custom sidebar via module magento

Tags: design

i want to add custom sidebar to category via custom design. i added below code but it is not working

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Abc_Design>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Abc_Design>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <design>
        <class>Abc_Design_Helper</class>
      </design>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

in admin category > custom design

```
   <reference name="left">
        <block type="abc/design" name="new_block_name" template="smartwave/porto/template/design.phtml" after="adjacent_block_name" />
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to declare your blocks in the `config.xml` file

Under the `<global>` tag add this:

```
<blocks>
  <design>
    <class>Abc_Design_Block</class>
  </design>
</blocks>
```

Then you should be able to use the block like this:

```
<block type="design/block_name_here"....>
```

So if your block class is `Abc_Design_Block_Something` you can use it as

```
<block type="design/something"....>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per as your config.xml code,you need to define block type.On custom Design section you have  add block type but you did not define block class.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Abc_Design>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Abc_Design>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <design>
        <class>Abc_Design_Helper</class>
      </design>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
    <design> <!--block prefix -->
        <class>Abc_Design_Block</class>
    </design>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

As i define block prefix `design` at config.xml on 
code should be.

```
  <reference name="left">
        <block type="design/design" name="new_block_name" template="smartwave/porto/template/design.phtml" after="adjacent_block_name" />
    </reference>
```

when block type    `design/design` is emuluate then excute as `Abc_Design_Block` (as design/ ) class prefix and     rest design execute as Design

then final class should be    `Abc_Design_Block_Design`.

if block type is design/amit then it execute as `design/` =`Abc_Design_Block` and amit as '`Amit`'.Final class is `Abc_Design_Block_Amit`

Comment: can u please update code

Comment: updated...can please tell me what is total path of design.phtml is app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/smartwave/porto/template/design.Am i right?